# Japanese Multiplication simulation - is a program actually capable of improving calculation speed?

Tags: math, theory, cpu

I'd like to write a simulation of Japanese Multiplication to get benchmarks on large calculations utilizing the shortcut vs traditional CPU multiplication. **I'm curious as to whether it makes sense to try this.**

[image]

**My Question:** I'd like to know whether or not a software math shortcut, as described above is actually a shortcut at all.

This is a question of programming concept. By utilizing the simulation of Japanese Multiplication, **is a program actually capable of improving calculation speed? Or am I doomed from the start?**

---

**The answer to this question isn't *required* to determine whether or not the experiment will succeed**, but rather whether or not it's logically possible for such a thing to occur in any program, using this concept as an example.

---

**My theory** is that since addition is computed faster than multiplication, a simulation of Japanese multiplication may actually allow a program to multiply (large) numbers faster than the CPU arithmetic unit can. I think this would be a very interesting finding, if it proves to be true.

If, in the multiplication of numbers of **any immense size**, the shortcut were to calculate the result via less instructions (or faster) than traditional ALU multiplication, I would consider the experiment a success.

Comment: I will immediately and without thinking about the technical details offer you a 100:1 bet that you cannot improve computing speed that way. Algorithms for doing arithmetic are a *thoroughly* researched topic. There is no chance whatsoever that you're the first person to think of implementing a well-known "manual" algorithm in software.

Comment: You have ventured onto a professional programmers venue with no apparent understanding or indication of how your question could possibly be relevant, or how it could possibly be answered. I don't think this question belongs here.

Comment: @david.pfx:  Programmers (of all stripes, not just professionals) come here to learn things they don't know about, and whether or not software can ever beat hardware is not only relevant to all programmers, it's answerable.

Comment: I agree with Michael and I will add that even if you did implement it, it would be software implementation against hardware implementation in ALU, which is specifically optimized for such operation. So even if you did create a benchmark, it would have zero value.

Comment: If you're interested in numbers of "immense size", consider Fuhrer's algorithm. It is the fastest (asymptotic) multiplication algorithm (publicly) known to mankind. In any case, I am confident this japanese multiplication algorithm is probably no faster than standard "schoolboy" multiplication, possibly slower, I think the standard algorithm can also be parallelized quite easily (not that you would want to, if it's slow you use a faster algorithm).

Comment: Crosspost: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/25861/japanese-multiplication-simulation-is-a-program-actually-capable-of-improving

Comment: Your algorithm is basically a way of simulating a mechanical computer on paper. If it was faster to do multiplication this way, processor architects would already lay out their circuits using it.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post the same question across StackExchange sites](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/25861/japanese-multiplication-simulation-is-a-program-actually-capable-of-improving).  If you feel you have posted in the wrong place then flag for a moderator and we will look into migrating it for you.  Thank you.

Comment: Meta Discussion: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6663/can-i-ask-this-question-about-the-effectiveness-of-a-mathematical-programming-co/6664?noredirect=1#6664 @maple_shaft

Answer (score 22):

This multiplication algorithm does not replace multiplication with addition. Instead, it splits the multiplication into a number of smaller multiplications that are easier for humans to understand. Humans (unlike computers) deal well with patterns and symbols, less so with large numbers (where “large“ means “multiple digits”).

```
321 × 254

  × |  2E2 +  5E1 +  4E0
----|-------------------
3E2 |  6E4 + 15E3 + 12E2
 +  |   +      +      +
2E1 |  3E3 + 10E2 +  8E1
 +  |   +      +      +
1E0 |  2E2 +  5E1 +  4E0

SUM = 81534
```

Those weird diagonals in your picture just group the small multiples with the same exponent together, which makes adding easier.

This algorithm can immediately be generalized to the multiplication of big integers, by dividing the input numbers into pieces half the size of native integers. The lower half of an integer is then the “first digit”, the upper half is the carry digit. Remember that a multiplication of two *n*-bit integers results in a *2n*-bit integer, which is why we need that extra space. During addition, possible overflows have to be handled manually (which makes this algorithm inefficient).

So we could apply this algorithm to base 2<sup>16</sup> or base 2<sup>32</sup>.
It is not appropriate to apply this algorithm to base 2: here builtin multiplication will very likely be faster than anything else.

Your “Japanese Multiplication” is just a visual interpretation of [lattice multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Lattice_multiplication). It suffers from having *O(n²)* complexity, and faster algorithms exist.

Answer (score 13):

Unsurprisingly, you are indeed "doomed from the start".

This "Japanese Multiplication" (which is a visual form of the [grid method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_method_multiplication) tought in UK primary schools since the 1990s) has a time complexity of at least O(n^2) where n is the number of digits in the numbers you are multiplying. This is because the number of intersections will be n*n, and you have to deal with each of them.

This is the same as traditional [long multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_multiplication#Long_multiplication).

[Toom-Cook-multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) is about O(n^1.465), and there are better ones by now (their complexity isn't a straight exponential though).

Answer (score 5):

> ...is a program actually capable of improving calculation speed? Or am I doomed from the start?

In pathological cases that are no longer relevant because the environments in which they occurred have fallen into disuse, probably.  In practical situations where you're making apples-to-apples comparisons, not on your life.

Look at speed in terms of instruction cycle budget.  On Intel CPUs, an integer multiply has a latency of three cycles.  That's your budget.  Anything you do has to beat that number to be considered an improvement.  Three cycles isn't much.

Let's be very generous and go on the assumption that the numbers you're handed are in binary-coded decimal (e.g., the decimal number `1234` is represented as `0x1234`).  This means that there's no multiplication involved, just logical shifts and AND operations to mask off the digit we want.  Those consume one cycle each (less depending on the state of the pipeline, but let's not complicate it).  Isolating a digit therefore takes two cycles, storing it someplace to be dealt with later is a third and incrementing the counter for where it's stored is a fourth.  The three-cycle budget has been exceeded by 33% just doing the first digits' worth of prep for your shortcut.

Like early CPUs, humans don't have a built-in multiplication instruction, so it has to be done the hard way.  If you get good enough with the shortcut, odds are good you'll be able to do large multiplications in fewer mental cycles than doing it the long way.  But, as Michael Borgwardt's answer points out, this is still long multiplication that's been optimized to run faster in [wetware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetware_%28brain%29).  CPUs do it in ways that have been optimized to run faster in electrical circuits.  Multiplication is a new enough concept that another hundred million years may pass before we evolve groups of neurons that can do it instantly.  We probably won't, because we've figured out how to get our machines to do it on our behalf.

Comment: This is not about machine vs. human. CPU instructions work with fixed length integers; they are irrelevant to this question, which is really about working with arbitrary length numbers. And there have been substantial advances in multiplication algorithms as late as 2007.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt:  What would stop us from developing a CPU that can do arbitrary-length long multiplication in hardware in one instruction if we found a need for it?

Comment: @Blrftl: the fact that hardware is just another implementation of an algorithm and the best multiplication algorithm we know is slower than O(n), let alone constant time. Using hardware you can trade space for time by parallel execution, but that doesn't matter unless you postulate self-replicating hardware.